# REST approach for Twitter facing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, twitter, restful-authentication, omniauth

whenever I do a GET

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/UID.json
http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/?ids%5B%5D=74776862
```

or

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

I am getting this error

```
{"error":"This method requires authentication.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json"}
```

and Response as

```
"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://api.twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2F1%2Ffollowers%2F%3Fids%255B%255D%3D74776862\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

should I pass somehing else also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the twitter [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth).  You have several options for Authentication.  For a RESTful service [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) is the way to go.

Comment: I am using Twitter API for Authentication, after that I have got token and secret hashes , now I am not able to get how to use them got a GET or POST request to Twitter, please help